# Trying to Parse XML String from HTTP Request in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xmlhttprequest

As a preface:  I cannot imagine this has not been asked before, but I have failed miserably at finding a solution...and I would think there is a simple solution and I am simply doing something completely wrong.

I have a simple index.php file that looks like so:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo "DATA : " . $data;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data, 0, true);
echo "XML : " . $xml;

$RoundTrip = (string) $xml->RoundTrip;
$TransactionId = (string) $xml->TransactionId;

?>
```

The echo "DATA" shows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><msg><head><Client>Test</Client><RoutingArea>811</RoutingArea><Source>MySRC</Source><Destination>BSRC</Destination><Version>2.27</Version><RoundTrip>ID=001088129291102</RoundTrip><TransactionId>12652b05-ceb9-11eb-a091-00505687f2ee</TransactionId><ServerId>03</ServerId></head><body><POdated>
```

...and the SimpleXMLElement is throwing an error:

```
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;msg&gt;&lt;head
```

As if the string is being read as URLencoded...but the initial output is not URLencoded.

**My Goal is to:** receive the XML doc from the request as a string and be able to parse it.

Comment: Check your original string isn't being formatted by the browser by viewing the actual source.

Comment: @NigelRen I am not doing any of this in the browser. this is all on the server. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It expects a file-path or URL, not file-content (because the 3rd parameter is `true`, while the default is `false`).

Try removing the 3rd parameter like:

```php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data, 0);
```

But if that does not work you still have the option:

```php
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

// do something with $xml
```

Comment: Your 2nd option is what worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter is `$dataIsURL` and you are specifying `true`.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php

> **dataIsURL**
>
> By default, dataIsURL is false. Use true to specify that data is a path or URL to an XML document instead of string data.

So, either change to `false`:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($tag, 0, false);
```

Or remove that third parameter:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($tag, 0);
```

Since you are providing a string and not a URL.